# Contact form 7 wordpress files attachment

Tags: wordpress, server, contact-form

I use the plugin "Contact Form 7".

I have a contact form which contains 5 inputs "type files". They have a limit of 4Mb each. 
When I submit the form with 5 images of 2Mb, I get the error "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later." The limit of 4Mb per file is **not** reached. 
However, when I submit the form with 5 images of 1Mb each, it works.

I deactivated all the plugins, I switched to the vanilla theme "Twenty seventeen", I reinstalled the plugin "Contact Form 7" but it does not work. Even on an another wordpress.

I don't know if the problem comes from the plugin or from the server.

The website is hosted by OVH. I looked into the `phpinfo()` and I found `upload_max_filesize : 128MB`. So it is not a limit problem from the server.

I installed the plugin on a local server but the problem is still here.

What do you think about it ?

Comment: What's your `post_max_size`?

Comment: The post_max_size is set to 64MO

Answer (score 0):

I think it refers u cant upload more than 4 Mo at once(all your photos must have in total around 4 Mo).
Edit: I think this can help u. :)
     https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/

Comment: I don't think, I set the limit to 1MO each and uploaded 900ko for each, it worked

Comment: It is set to 1mb when there is no file limit specified.